# Visual Studio 2015 Application Doesn't Fully Close

Tags: visual-studio-2015

I've written a VB.NET WinForm application inside of VS2015 Professional.  When I run the project within VS and close the application the debug doesn't fully stop.  I have to physically click the stop running to get it to close close down.

The project uses two other API's that I've been working with for months without an issue and I go thru the routines to close the API's before closing my application (Application.Exit).

If I compile and run the project as an executable without VS the form closes but the executable remains running until I terminate the process.

Can anyone point me to a resource that will help me figure out what is still running or why the application won't fully close.

Comment: I don't know if any proper way exists, but I see some options. You can use a profiler to “profile” your app after you try to close it. A profiler will show what methods are being executed.

Answer (score 0):

Found that "Make single instance application" is causing the problem when checked.  If unchecked the application opens and closes without a problem.  Deferring to the development team now that I have proof.

Cheers!